# Include images under asstes directory in production mode

Tags: image, angular, assets, production-environment

What is the best way to include image saved in assests in `html` file? I have an image under the `assets` directory and when I run `build prod` mode those images are not found (`http 404`) any more.

[image]
[image]

Comment: check the dist folder whether the assets folder is created or not

Comment: It is created. I see it in ide

Answer (score 0):

Have you think to use a different command line to run your build prod? Can you test to generate your dist with:

ng build --env=prod --output-hashing

We are using this command line to generate our projects on prod mode and all assets works fine.